# Term for women who claims to be feminist but are actually selfish

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

There are some women (self proclaimed feminist) who says they believe in equal rights but at the same time they expect

- Their husband to be working on better paying job than them
- Men to offer them seat in case no vacant seat is available in public transports
- Men to always pay for their dinner on dates

along with many other things. They are not true feminist. They are selfish persons who only care about themselves. Is there any special term/phrase for such women?

Comment: The latter list has nothing to do with feminism... and guys offering seats on buses is just polite behavior but it's not expected... at least by me... I mean, if the woman was pregnant, that'd be one thing but I usually decline offers of seats on buses.

Comment: @Catija Oops sorry. Edited it. What I mean here is they believe in equal pay for same job. But expect their husband to be working on a better paying job that them. (Just trying to give an example).

"guys offering seats on buses is just polite behavior but it's not expected... at least by me... I mean, if the woman was pregnant, that'd be one thing but I usually decline offers of seats on buses"

Yeah but some perfectly healthy women with no bags or babies expect men to offer them seat at least where I live. Of course not all women are like this

Comment: This has nothing to do with feminism, though. You'd be more correct in removing the first half of the question and asking "what do you call women who expect:" followed by your list of three things. No true "feminist" would expect those things.  They're all old-fashioned concepts that are dying a slow death, and are, if anything, anti-feminist or sexist concepts.

Comment: @Catija Sadly but I know a lot of women who call themselves feminist and say how they believe in equal rights but still expect these things.

Comment: You're describing selfish behavior, and attributing it to feminism.  Your problem isn't your command of English, my friend.

Comment: An informal/slang term for such people: SJW. (Social justice warrior)

Comment: Is there a reason you believe that there is a better word than hypocrite? What word would you use in your native language?

Answer (score 2):

That's either **misandry** (the male version of misogyny) or **hypocrisy**, depending on how you look at it.

It has nothing to do with feminism except perhaps being its opposite, sort of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to avoid going on a rant about these hypocritical women considering themselves feminists and say that they're asking for men to be **[chivalrous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chivalrous)**:

> behaving in an honorable or polite way especially toward women
>
> showing respect and politeness especially toward women

But even the examples you state are more extreme than the current accepted terms of chivalry:

> [Modern Chivalry](http://www.gq.com/life/mens-lives/201409/how-to-be-chivalrous)
>
> Yes, chivalry is alive and well—thing is, you're doing it wrong. That ye olde code of conduct that taught guys how to be nice to damsels in distress isn't, well, up to code. First, they're not in distress: Today women can open their own doors, sometimes to their own offices, where they sign your paychecks. And second, that behavior just makes you look silly. That's why we had Lauren Bans come up with the new rules of chivalry.

If you read through the examples, even this list doesn't allow for the man **always** paying.

And it also doesn't really apply to the second one... which is really more tied to the concept of the man as breadwinner and woman as homemaker.